How can I use the midpoint approximation method to find area under a graph?
Use the midpoint approximation method to find the area under the curve of f(x)=1-x^2 over the interval [-1,1].

Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. This stack site serves the Mathematica and the Wolfram language communities. Perhaps you would like to post this question at the MathSE site instead. Thanks.

For site visitors interested in a Mathematica solution, please visit the function repository.

Another way:
midptRule = Function[{partition, f}, 
  (f /@ MovingAverage[partition, 2]) . Differences[partition]];

midptRule[Subdivide[-1., 1., 20], x |-> 1 - x^2]

(*  1.335  *)

With a random partition:
SeedRandom[1];
midptRule[Union[{-1., 1.}, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100]], x |-> 1 - x^2]

(*  1.33364  *)


neat, esp random partition +1 :)

One possible way
f[x_]:=1-x^2;
nRectangles=20; (*use even number only*)
from =-1;
to = 1;
delX=(to-from)/nRectangles;
midpoints=FindDivisions[{from,to},2*nRectangles];
area = Sum[ f[ midpoints[[2*n]]]* delX,{n,1,nRectangles}];
N[%]

Gives
(*1.335*)

Compare to
Integrate[f[x], {x, from, to}] // N

(*1.33333*)

